# is fillRect faster than fillOval?

Tags: java, graphics, fill

I'm sure it's not that much of a difference, but would fillRect be faster than fillOval, considering there's less math to do, just 4 points vs messing with pi, etc?

Comment: Probably, but I wouldn't let it affect the choice of how I want the screen to appear, except in some extreme cases.

Comment: The implementation is platform specific, so sometimes probably other times maybe not

Answer (score 0):

`fillRect` obviously requires no trigonometry (or even multiplications), so *must* be faster.

Unless the developer was some colossal idiot which I doubt.

The speed penalty of sines and cosines far outweigh the gain from drawing fewer pixels in `fillOval`.

Comment: `fillOval` might not require much trigonometry.  It's possible to compute successive points on an ellipse by computing the sine and cosine of an angle _once_, and thereafter using `newX = c1*x+c2*y+c3; newY=c4*x+c5*y+c6;` for some constants `c1` through `c6`. Whether this is good enough to fill the ellipse decently, I'm not sure.